# Are keys and values the same in ES6 set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I was just going through the MDN documentation for **[set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** , and how it works , coming to the part of how to iterate over a set , i saw the following examples:

```
// logs the items in the order: 1, "some text", {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
for (let item of mySet) console.log(item);
```

And

```
// logs the items in the order: 1, "some text", {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
for (let item of mySet.values()) console.log(item);
```

And

```
// logs the items in the order: 1, "some text", {"a": 1, "b": 2} 
//(key and value are the same here)
for (let [key, value] of mySet.entries()) console.log(key);
```

Just to confirm , does this mean that when using set the keys and values are the same ?

Comment: If a `Set` would contain key/value pairs how would it differ from `Map` then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The entries() method returns a new Iterator object that contains an array of [value, value] for each element in the Set object, in insertion order [...].

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries)

So no, Sets don't have keys at all, however `.entries()` lets you believe so for having consistency between Maps and Sets.

Comment: Perfect ! that explain it  :)