# What is the use case for Set.prototype.entries()?

Tags: javascript, set

In JavaScript there is a method `entries()` that returns an iterator object with array of the key and value for each item in the `Set`. But `key` and `value` in `Set` are the same thing. So what would be the use case for this, especially given the other iterator methods that exist for `Set`?

e.g.

```
const mySet = new Set([1,2,3]);
for (let arr of mySet.entries()) console.log(arr)

// Outputs:
// [1,1]
// [2,2]
// [3,3]
```

Comment: Take a look at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries) they describe the 'why' in the first text

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338362/why-would-i-use-es6-set-prototype-entries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100017/are-keys-and-values-the-same-in-es6-set